# Can I use a member element as the default argument for a method of the class?

Tags: c++

The method `Minimum` returns the minimum element in the binary search tree. If no argument is passed it prints the minimum of calling object. If address of a node is passed it prints the minimum of the subtree whose root is node

When compiled it shows "Invalid use of non static data member `Tree::root`"

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
class Node
{
public:
    Node *leftchild;
    Node *rightchild;
    Node *parent;
    int info;
};

class Tree
{
public:
    Node *root;
    Tree()
    {
        root=NULL;
    }
    void Minimum(Node*);
};

void Tree::Minimum(Node *curnode=root)
{
    Node *parent;
    while(curnode!=NULL)
    {
        parent=curnode;
        curnode=curnode->leftchild;
    }
    std::cout<<parent->info<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Tree tree;
    tree.Minimum();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that your Minimum implementation has undefined behaviour with NULL as argument.

Comment: Not an answer but you should rather provide the default argument in the _declaration_, not the definition (i.e. `void Minimum(Node* = default_value);` then `void Tree::Minimum(Node *curnode) { ... }`), so that it can be called without argument given only the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot.

For the default value you can use either a value, a variable or a function that is accessible in the context of the *function definition* that is, in the class definition, which is outside of any particular object's context.

It usually helps me thinking on how the compiler really processes this. In particular, when the compiler does overload resolution for a function and finds an overload that has more arguments than those used at the place of call, the compiler will generate code at the place of call to fill in the rest of the arguments. The generated code will *always* generate a call with *all* of the arguments:

```
int g();
void f(int x = g()); 
int main() {
    f();               // [1]
}
```

When the compiler processes [1] and it does overload resolution it finds that `void ::f(int x = g())` is the best candidate and picks it up. It then fills the default argument and generates the call for you:

```
int main() {
    f( /*compiler injected*/g() );
}
```

If you consider a call to a member function, or a member variable of the class, it would not make sense in the context of the caller (the language could be changed to adapt to this, it is not impossible to handle that, but with the current model it does not work).

Comment: The default can be a function call and it's evaluated in each place the function is *called*? I always thought it had to be a constant!

Comment: @jcoder: It can be a few things... it can be a function and it will be used whenever the default argument is needed (or never if all calls provide the argument), it could be a variable with static storage duration, it could be an expression yielding a different type with a user conversion and the conversion will be evaluated with each call (that needs the default value)...

Comment: Hmm, I leaned something today!

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively set it to `NULL` for example as default, and then check and set it to the member in the method.

Or overload the method with `void Minimum();` and in that method call the one with an argument with the member.

```
void Tree::Minimum() {
    Minimum(root);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any way to get the default parameter to work like that. But you can get the same result by overloading the function, like so:

```
class Tree
{
public:
    Node *root;
    Tree()
    {
        root=NULL;
    }
    void Minimum(Node*);
    void Minimum();
};

void Tree::Minimum(Node *curnode)
{
    Node *parent;
    while(curnode!=NULL)
    {
        parent=curnode;
        curnode=curnode->leftchild;
    }
    std::cout<<parent->info<<std::endl;
}

void Tree::Minimum()
{
    Minimum(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the case where an argument of `NULL` is explicitly passed doesn't need to be differentiated from no argument being passed, you could set `NULL` as the default and use `root` if `curnode` is `NULL`.

```
void Tree::Minimum(Node *curnode=NULL)
{
    if (curnode==NULL)
        curnode = root;
    Node *parent;
    while(curnode!=NULL)
    {
        parent=curnode;
        curnode=curnode->leftchild;
    }
    std::cout<<parent->info<<endl;
}
```